# Is there a way to include folders in client assets folder while creating spfx package

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, asset-library

I have a spfx project with a list view command set and webpart, they are using some third party artifacts which are there in "dist" folder that needs to be deployed to appcatalog (tenant or site collection) "clientassets" library.
In the "package-soution.json" I have "includeClientSideAssets": true, but it only includes the listview commandset and webpart assets.

At the moment I am doing this manually.

in npmignore file I have a entry "!dist" in gitignore I have a entry for "dist"

Options explored:
cdnBasePath (here also I have to put the files manually)
gulp -spsave (requires user credentials, so not a option)

Comment: Did you try removing entries for "dist" folder from ignore files?

Comment: yes from npmignore, not from gitignore

Comment: Tried removing from both not working, added a entry in "package.json" for "files": ["dist"] still the folder not included in sppkg file,

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a PowerShell script to create a folder in "clientassets" library in app catalog site and upload the artifacts to it.